# Haskell vs C speed: Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c, performance, haskell, math, implementation

Haskell one is implemented using optimized Data.IntSet with complexity O(lg n). However, there is a 15x (previously 30x) speed difference for n = 2000000 despite Haskell code is already optimized for even number cases. I would like to know whether/why my implementation in Haskell is imperfect.

### Original Haskell

```
primesUpTo :: Int -> [Int]
primesUpTo n = 2 : put S.empty [3,5..n]
    where put :: S.IntSet -> [Int] -> [Int]
          put _ [] = []
          put comps (x:xs) =
            if S.member x comps
            then put comps xs
            else x : put (S.union comps multiples) xs
                where multiples = S.fromList [x*2, x*3 .. n]
```

### Update

`fromDistinctAscList` gives a 4x speed increase. 2-3-5-7-Wheel speeds up by another 50%.

```
primesUpTo :: Int -> [Int]
primesUpTo n = 2 : 3 : 5 : 7 : put S.empty (takeWhile (<=n) (spin wheel 11))
    where put :: S.IntSet -> [Int] -> [Int]
          put _ [] = []
          put comps (x:xs) =
            if S.member x comps
            then put comps xs
            else x : put (S.union comps multiples) xs
                where multiples = S.fromDistinctAscList [x*x, x*(x+2) .. n]
          spin (x:xs) n = n : spin xs (n + x)
          wheel = 2:4:2:4:6:2:6:4:2:4:6:6:2:6:4:2:6:4:6:8:4:2:4:2:4:8:6:4:6:2:4:6:2:6:6:4:2:4:6:2:6:4:2:4:2:10:2:10:wheel
```

### Benchmarking

All time are measured by *nix `time` command, real space

```
Haskell original : 2e6: N/A;    2e7: >30s
Haskell optimized: 2e6: 0.396s; 2e7: 6.273s
C++ Set (ordered): 2e6: 4.694s; 2e7: >30s
C++ Bool Array   : 2e6: 0.039s; 2e7: 0.421s
```

Haskell optimized is slower than C++ Bool by 10~15x, and faster than C++ Set by 10x.

### Source code

C Compiler options: g++ 5.3.1, `g++ -std=c++11`
Haskell options: ghc 7.8.4, `ghc`

C code (Bool array) http://pastebin.com/W0s7cSWi

```
 prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
 for (int i=2; i<=limit; i++) { //edited
     if (!prime[i]) continue;
     for (int j=2*i; j<=n; j+=i)
        prime[j] = false;
 }
```

C code (Set) http://pastebin.com/sNpghrU4

```
 nonprime.insert(1);
 for (int i=2; i<=limit; i++) { //edited
     if (nonprime.count(i) > 0) continue;
     for (int j=2*i; j<=n; j+=i)
        nonprime.insert(j);
 }
```

Haskell code http://pastebin.com/HuMqwvRW
Code as written above.

Comment: Change `pastebin` to `pastehere`...

Comment: Array access is `O(1)` rather than `O(log n)` -- so I wouldn't expect the code to be comparable. Also, if Haskell is using arbitrary precision arithmetic (which I think it does) and C is using fixed-length ints, there would be a difference traceable to that.

Comment: I think type annotations forced Haskell to use I64d in this case

Comment: Really sorry for not pasting the code here, I am still new to stackoverflow

Comment: @JohnColeman Haskell's `Int` is standard 32-bit integer (to be honest, at least 29-bit by specification), while `Integer` is arbitrary size.

Comment: Your Haskell code has function calls such as `fromList` and `union` which have no direct analog in the C code -- I don't see why you would expect the code to be competitive.

Comment: @lisyarus Thanks. I wasn't sure about that part. I had in the back of my mind an issue that Python 3 is slower with ints than Python 2, largely for this reason, and thought that a similar thing might be true with Haskell.

Comment: @John Coleman Thanks for the insight. Originally I guess that IntSet and other optimizations, eg union can make up the difference, and lg 2e5 should be small enough to lessen the spees difference... But oddly C code runs in 8 sec if stl set is used, far slower than the functional Haskell version...

Comment: If you want to do this kind of benchmarking, please show *the whole program* (the Haskell one *and* the C you're comparing against), the compiler versions and compilation options used, and how the timings were recorded. It's not impossible that (for example) finding the primes takes no time at all, and it's *printing* them that's slow. Also, Haskell is lazy and has a habit of not computing what you think it's computing. So please, show us the whole program and what you're actually measuring.

Comment: Where is the source?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I deliberately involve no I/O above. Timings were recorded by *nix `time` command. I don't know how to correct the lazy computation issue, and thought it hardly matters.

Comment: Your C code loop is wrong, It is iterating way too many times. It should be `for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)` Compiled as C (with `gcc` and `-Ofast` optimization) 2e6 gives `sys     0m0.018s`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My fault. But isn't time should be measured in `real` space instead of `sys`?

Comment: "Haskell options: `ghc`" Do I take it you're *not* using the `-O` switch to turn on compiler optimisations? (I don't know if that makes any difference here, I'm just checking.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, to avoid bias I didn't turn any optimizations on

Comment: @MarcoXerox Interesting. I would have benchmarked both languages with typical optimisations turned on... (After all, that's typically how you use them.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I was solving some older problems on Codeforces, which to my knowledge defaults to no optimizations, when I come across this issue of implementing prime sieve over N=1e7 numbers. In the end I didn't manage to hone my Haskell skills over that problem and resort to C/C++ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know whether/why my implementation in Haskell is imperfect.

Instead of [`fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html#v:fromList) you better use [`fromDistinctAscList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html#v:fromDistinctAscList) which performs *linearly*. You may also add *only odd multiples* starting with x*x not x*2, because all the smaller odd multiples have already been added. Style-wise, a right fold may fit better than recursion.

Doing so, I get more than 3 times performance improvement for n equal to 2,000,000:

```
import Data.IntSet (member, union, empty, fromDistinctAscList)

sieve :: Int -> [Int]
sieve n = 2: foldr go (const []) [3,5..n] empty
    where
    go i run obs
        | member i obs = run obs
        | otherwise    = i: run (union obs inc)
        where inc = fromDistinctAscList [i*i, i*(i + 2)..n]
```

Nevertheless, an array has both O(1) access and *cache friendly* memory allocation. Using mutable arrays, I see more than 15 times performance improvement over your Haskell code (again n equal to 2,000,000):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Array.ST (STUArray)
import Control.Monad (forM_, foldM)
import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)
import Data.Array.Base (newArray, unsafeWrite, unsafeRead)

sieve :: Int -> [Int]
sieve n = reverse $ runST $ do
    arr <- newArray (0, n) False :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
    foldM (go arr) [2] [3,5..n]
    where
    go arr acc i = do
        b <- unsafeRead arr i
        if b then return acc else do
            forM_ [i*i, i*(i + 2).. n] $ \k -> unsafeWrite arr k True
            return $ i: acc
```

Comment: Thank you! But if `STUArray` is much more faster, what justifies the use of `IntSet`, except for `findMin` or `findMax`?

Comment: @MarcoXerox Two things: `STUArray` is not a pure functional structure, which means that you can only run it in an `ST` (state thread), whereas `IntSet` is properly pure, so you can pass it along and use it throughout your program. The second thing is that each data structure has things it's good at and things it's bad at. For a sieve, the mutable array is simply king. That doesn't mean that an array is always the best to use -- and certainly it isn't.

Comment: @MicroVirus Array is often used in C and List is ubiquitous in Python similarly. But then, admittedly as a Haskell newbie most tutorials I've read only use arrays as a tool for memoization; instead they use linked list, sequence etc which are referred as purely functional. On the contrary arrays, heaps, segment trees etc offer much better lookup times. I can enclose array operations in C styled functions and return pointers to pass them along too. I don't really understand the benefits of purely functional structures.